# string 型のスライスが空になる

Tags: go

下記の関数を用いてstring型のスライスを逆順に並べ替えました。しかし、戻ってきた値が空のスライスになってしまいます。
なぜでしょうか

```golang
func reverseTweets(tweets []string) []string {
    result := make([]string, len(tweets))
    cnt := 0
    for i := len(tweets) - 1; i <= 0; i++ {
        result[cnt] = tweets[i]
        cnt++
    }
    return result
}
tweets = reverseTweets(tweets)
```

Comment: すみません。もう片方を消しました。

Comment: `for i := len(tweets) - 1; i >= 0; i-- { ... }` ではないでしょうか。

Comment: できました!ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```golang
for i := len(tweets) - 1; i >= 0; i-- { ... }
```

ではないでしょうか。

---

本題とは関係はないのですが、スライスの内容を逆順に並べ替える方法として以下の様な方法もあります。新たなスライスを作らずに対象のスライスを直接変更します。

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func reverseTweets(tw []string) {
    for i, j := 0, len(tw)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        tw[i], tw[j] = tw[j], tw[i]
    }
}

func main() {
    tweets := []string{"foo", "bar", "baz", "Hello", "World"}
    reverseTweets(tweets)
    fmt.Println(tweets)
}
=> [World Hello baz bar foo]
```

ご参考までにどうぞ。

Comment: ありがとう御座います。こちらのほうがメモリ効率がよくていいですね。使用させて頂きます。